# insert all rows where not exist same data of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for columns:

```
id,
pregnew,
entryDate,
unionID
```

The table is populated with this data:
[image: Screenshot]

I want to insert into another table with sub query of select. Before inserting a row I want to verify unionID column if the value for current month is already exist. If exist, then the query should ignore inserting that row and move to insert next row.

Here is the query I have tried:

```
insert into pg2(pregNew, unionID, entryDate) select pregNew, unionID, entryDate from fpipg2
where  month(pg3.entryDate)=month(current_date) and not exists (select unionID from mis4pg2 where month(pg2.entryDate)=month(current_date))
```

With this query I expect, entryDate value 2018-08-19 and unionID value 2 should be ignored. But it is stopping after first insert. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mention two tables in your text, but your query is referencing yet another, `mis4pg2` and a non-existent alias (`pg3`).

Comment: I highly recommend using descriptive names rather than names such as: pg2, pg3, fpipg2, mis4pg2, etc.

Comment: Removed unrelated comments; fixed grammar and spelling; added missing punctuation; added some much-needed whitespace to the code snippet for readability.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you only want to insert rows from the current month that do not exist.  You are highly advised to validate the year as well as the month.

This suggests an `exists` query, like this:

```
insert into pg2 (pregNew, unionID, entryDate)
    select pregNew, unionID, entryDate
    from fpipg2 p2
    where year(pg2.entryDate) = year(current_date) and
          month(pg2.entryDate) = month(current_date) and
          not exists (select 1
                      from pg2 ppg2
                      where ppg2.unionid = p2.unionid and
                            year(ppg2.entryDate) = year(p2.entryDate) and
                            month(ppg2.entryDate) = month(p2.entryDate) and
                     );
```

Comment: If the query is relation then it does not work. For example: insert into mis4pg2 (pregNew,anc1stVisit, unionID, entryDate)
    select p2.pregNew,p2.anc1stVisit+p3.anc1stVisit, p2.unionID, p2.entryDate
    from fpipg2 p2 join mis3part1 p3 on p2.unionID=p3.unionID
    where year(p2.entryDate) = year(current_date) and month(p2.entryDate) = month(current_date) and
    not exists (select 1
    from mis4pg2 ppg2
        where ppg2.unionid = p2.unionid and
        year(ppg2.entryDate) = year(p2.entryDate) and
        month(ppg2.entryDate) = month(p2.entryDate)
        );